# Variable de ambiente PHP de xampp no se agrega al path

Tags: php, windows, xampp

Estoy instalando Xampp usando la consola de comando de windows de manera desatendida. Cuando termina la instalacion xampp se instala bien a excepcion de que la variable de ambiente `PHP` no se agrega a PATH en las variables del sistema. Estoy usando windows 7. 
Quiero saber si hay una forma de agregarla sin tener que recurrir a meterme por configuracion del sistema, sino solo usando la consola. 
Intente con `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\php` pero cuando cierro y vuelvo a abrir la consola no me reconoce el comando php.

Comment: Abrir una consola es por así decirlo instanciar una consola. Cuando ciertas, es cerrar un programa, por lo que se destruye. Para que se mantenga debes ir a la configuración de variables de entorno de tu sistema, en este caso win7.

Comment: Excatamente eso es lo que no quiero, puedo agregarla si me dirigo a configuracion del sistema. Sin embargo quiero agregarla sin tener que recurrir a eso y usando la consola de comandos.

Comment: Puede servirte esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28778358/3239070 (revisá bien la consecuencias de usar `setx`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tener privilegios de administrador, pero podrías hacerlo con **SETX**

```
SETX /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\xampp\php"
```

El parámetro **/M** se emplea para añadirlo a las variables del sistema. HKLM.

Deberás reiniciar la consola.

> **NOTA** Este comando tiene una limitación de 1024 caracteres. Se debe emplear con cuidado en la actualización de variables, ya que podría
>   producirse perdidas de información que comprometen el sistema.

Documentación completa en [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx)

Comment: Interesante. Desconocía ese comando.